# Nexmo SMS API "Unroutable message - rejected" Fatal error

Tags: php, vonage

I am using the Nexmo SMS API for sending SMS.
But I get following error:

> Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'Nexmo\Client\Exception\Request' with message 'Unroutable message - rejected'

What does this mean and how can I resolve the problem?

Answer (score 1):

From the [Nexmo knowledge base](https://help.nexmo.com/hc/en-us/articles/204014663-Error-11-Unroutable-what-does-it-mean-):

> Error 11 - Unroutable refers to message failed due to not route available to deliver message to the number in question.

There could be any number of reasons that a message is unroutable - from the number not existing to Nexmo not being able to deliver to a specific number.

To find out why this specific number is not routable, [raise a ticket](https://help.nexmo.com/hc/en-us/requests/new) with Nexmo support.